# Binding to external XML doesn't work, but adding XML using XData makes it work

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, xaml, xmldataprovider

Here is the code for App.xaml:

```
<!-- <XmlDataProvider x:Key="BookmarkData" Source="testData.xml" XPath="/Favourites"/>-->

<XmlDataProvider x:Key="BookmarkData" XPath="/Favorites">
    <x:XData>
        <Favorites>
            <Bookmark>
                <Title>Google</Title>
                <URL>http://www.google.com</URL>
            </Bookmark>
            <Bookmark>
                <Title>Amazon</Title>
                <URL>http://www.amazon.com</URL>
            </Bookmark>
            <Bookmark>
                <Title>Slashdot</Title>
                <URL>http://www.slashdot.com</URL>
            </Bookmark>
            <Bookmark>
                <Title>Ars Technica</Title>
                <URL>http://www.arstechnica.com</URL>
            </Bookmark>
            <Bookmark>
                <Title>New Egg</Title>
                <URL>http://www.newegg.com</URL>
            </Bookmark>
        </Favorites>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

Commented out line isn't working. Path is correct.

Here is the XML file:

```
<Favorites>
        <Bookmark>
                  <Title>Google</Title>
                  <URL>http://www.google.com</URL>
        </Bookmark>
        <Bookmark>
                  <Title>Amazon</Title>
                  <URL>http://www.amazon.com</URL>
        </Bookmark>
        <Bookmark>
                  <Title>Slashdot</Title>
                  <URL>http://www.slashdot.com</URL>
        </Bookmark>
        <Bookmark>
                  <Title>Ars Technica</Title>
                  <URL>http://www.arstechnica.com</URL>
        </Bookmark>
        <Bookmark>
                 <Title>New Egg</Title>
                 <URL>http://www.newegg.com</URL>
        </Bookmark>
</Favorites>
```

Why binding is happening in one case, but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in XPath. Compare

```
XPath="/Favourites"
```

with

```
XPath="/Favorites"
```

Comment: Right!! That's is funny. I haven't written the XML, just copied a sample from the web to save time, author is probably American and I am used to British English and I couldn't spot it for quite a long time. Thanks!